# How to filter JSON data and then enumerate over that filtered data?

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I'm currently creating an app that uses "timed rewards" that only last for a specific amount of time, I'm new to using filters in Swift, the current objectives I need to meet:

1. Show reward if redemptionDate is NULL
2. Hide reward if currentDateTime >= redemptiondate + redeemTimeLimit (These are JSON Objects)
3. Show reward and display count down timer if currentDateTime < redemptiondate + redeemTimeLimit
4. Count down timer amount is the difference between redemptiondate + redeemTimeLimit and currentDateTime

Here is my code so far, I've run into a couple of crashes, the notes are in the code.  I've also numbered the areas where I try and meet the criteria above:

```
   var rewardsArray : [MemberRewardsInfo] = []//MemberRewarsInfo is a JSON Object custom class
  var timeFilteredRewardsArray : [MemberRewardsInfo] = []

 RewardManager.sharedInstance.updateRewards({ rewards in

self.timeFilteredRewardsArray = rewards


  //.1
  self.timeFilteredRewardsArray = self.timeFilteredRewardsArray.filter ({$0.redemptionDate == nil})


for filteredReward in self.timeFilteredRewardsArray {


  let Date = NSDate()
  let df = NSDateFormatter()
  df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
  df.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
  let currentDate = df.stringFromDate(Date)

  //.2
  if currentDate >= filteredReward.redemptionDate! + filteredReward.redeemTimeLimit! {

            //remove current reward from array, not sure how to do this

    //.3
  } else if currentDate < filteredReward.redemptionDate! + filteredReward.redeemTimeLimit!{

    //.4
    var countdownTimer = (filteredReward.redemptionDate! + filteredReward.redeemTimeLimit!) - currentDate

       //error occurs here: "Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands"
  }
}



   self.rewardsArray =  self.timeFilteredRewardsArray
    self.rewardsTableView.reloadData()

  })
```

Comment: Why would u filter your array...then assign it against the current array, while u are enumerating that array...your code look seriously wrong from the start

Comment: I thought so, what do you recommend a good way to approach this situation?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to filter rather than build?  i.e. Why not create an empty array and then enumerate "rewards", adding items that match your criteria to the array you created?

Comment: That sounds like it would be efficient, I'm trying to figure out a way to solve this issue and filtering then enumerating was the first thing I came up with.  If you see my comments in code, I ran into issues enumerating the array.

Comment: The error in #4 makes sense.  I think you are trying to do "date math", but those really are strings you have there.  So you can't "subtract" them.  An aside, I strongly recommend you not create the date formatter within the for loop.  They are crazy expensive to create for whatever reason...make one before the enumerate and keep reusing it.

Comment: I recomended to convert your date to timestamp eg.`timeIntervalSince1970` to calculate, so it become an Int and far more easier to do math stuff, but first you should fix your loop and array first

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this library [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). Swift is very strict about types, and JSON doesn't care about types. Also the chaining becomes a big mess, SwiftyJSON fixes all of that. It will help you focus on the filters, since you are filtering your array an then assigning it against the same array...

Quick example since I don't know your json structure:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["data"]["date"].string {
  //convert to date and do your filters
}
```